# Phonegap connection type returns null

Tags: android, jquery, eclipse, cordova

I want to get the connection type of my device, but the script return me null every time.

```
function verificaconexiunea(){
                var conexiune = navigator.connection.type;
                alert(conexiune);
                var status={};
                status["Connection.UNKNOWN"]  = 'Conexiune necunoscuta';
                status["Connection.ETHERNET"] = 'Conexiune Ethernet';
                status["Connection.WIFI"]     = 'Conexiune WiFi';
                status["Connection.CELL_2G"]  = 'Conexiune Internet 2G';
                status["Connection.CELL_3G"]  = 'Conexiune Internet 3G';
                status["Connection.CELL_4G"]  = 'Conexiune Internet 4G';
                status["Connection.NONE"]     = 'Fara conexiune internet!';
}
```

The variable "conexiune" always return 0.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Cordova? Did you wait for the deviceready event to fire?

Comment: Obviously devicready fire, because, how i said, that alert(conexiune); shows me "0". I use cordova 3.0.0.

Comment: Hmm, ok, I guess that is obvious but i wanted to be sure. So - did you add the connection plugin? Remember in Cordova 3 *every* single feature has to be added as a plugin.

Comment: Yes .. i added as a plugin in config.xml because plugins.xml doesn't exists. But still the same problem.

Comment: Adding it in config.xml is not good enough unless you're using PhoneGap Build. Are you? If you are building locally you need to add the plugin too.

Comment: Yes..i'm using phonegap build..how can i add the plugin?

Comment: Ah well then you do NOT have to add it. So I will say this - from what I know - the connection test is NOT always perfect. Since it doesn't throw an error but returns 0, it may mean it really can't just detect your connection. Are you on a 'odd' phone or a weird place connection-wise?

Comment: I have a lg oprimus black .. and the connection here supports 3G max signal ..:|

Comment: To be clear, PhoneGap Build still only supports 2.9, but that should be fine really. Unfortunately I don't have anything to suggest here. Since it returns 0 and not an error I'd assume it really can't read your device connection.